# TestCafe - How to click on "select class" when ID not available

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

[Showcase of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc6lW.png)

Unable to click on this dropdown list since it does not have an ID, how could I click on  this select class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classname, classname with the element name to locating the element.

```
await t.click(Selector("select.product_sort_container"));
```

You will have to master location strategies to locate elements in the web pages. All elements will not have IDs.

Reference :

1. [Select Page Elements](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements)
2. [Mastering CSS for web automation](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2021/01/05/mastering-css-for-selenium-test-automation-2/)

Recipe : [Test <Select> Elements](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402806/recipes/basics/test-select-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements) to learn how to use selectors to select elements.

Since your dropdown has an html attribute you can use [Selector.withAttribute Method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402742/reference/test-api/selector/withattribute).